# Nothing happening when a R file is called from my Java code

Tags: java, r, rjava

I have a java code which has R programming steps in it which is running perfectly fine. But the same R programming steps are extracted into a R file (MyScript.r) and I tried to call this file from my java code. When I run my java code nothing seems to be happening. I may look dumb with what I'm trying to achieve, may be it's true as I don't have knowledge on R. So required your help on this.

My Java code with R programming steps inside it.

```
package com.rtest;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class RWithJavaTest {

    public static void main(String a[]) {

        // Create an R vector in the form of a string.
        String javaVector = "c(1,2,3,4,5)";
//      System.out.println("System.getProperty(\"java.library.path\")>>"+System.getProperty("java.library.path"));  //Prints path in env var
        // Start Rengine.
        Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);

        // The vector that was created in JAVA context is stored in 'rVector'
        // which is a variable in R context.
        engine.eval("rVector=" + javaVector);

        // Calculate MEAN of vector using R syntax.
        engine.eval("meanVal=mean(rVector)");

        // Retrieve MEAN value
        double mean = engine.eval("meanVal").asDouble();

        // Print output values
        System.out.println("Mean of given vector is=" + mean);



    }
}
```

The above program when run, successfully giving me the output: 3.0

Java code with R programming steps included in R file and calling the R file from the java code.

```
package com.rtest;
import java.io.IOException;
public class RWithJavaTest {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {
            System.out.println("before..");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rscript D:\\MyScript.R");
            System.out.println("after..");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

R script:

```
// Create an R vector in the form of a string.
        String javaVector = "c(1,2,3,4,5)";
//      System.out.println("System.getProperty(\"java.library.path\")>>"+System.getProperty("java.library.path"));  //Prints path in env var
        // Start Rengine.
        Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);

        // The vector that was created in JAVA context is stored in 'rVector'
        // which is a variable in R context.
        engine.eval("rVector=" + javaVector);

        // Calculate MEAN of vector using R syntax.
        engine.eval("meanVal=mean(rVector)");

        // Retrieve MEAN value
        double mean = engine.eval("meanVal").asDouble();

        // Print output values
        System.out.println("Mean of given vector is=" + mean);
```

I know what I did here is something completely wrong but seeking help on 2 things here.
1) How to correct my R Script so that it runs with out any issues
2) Java code to call the R Script, so I can see the output 3.0 once I run the code.

Comment: In the second case you are calling `Rscript` from the system and `Rscript` expects a script in R! Your `MyScript.R` is written in java. It of course will complain of something.

Comment: Try to use all the path: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" D:\\MyScript.R`

Comment: @Enrique tried but no change in result

Comment: Have you tried with ProcessBuilder? `ProcessBuilder pid = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.0\\bin\\Rscript.exe", "D:\\MyScript.R");`

Comment: @Enrique still the same result. I doubt if my R script named MyScript.R is actually doing any thing. Can you just share a sample R script where I can call it and see some output. That way I will make sure we are on right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below lines of code obviously worked for me and it calls the R file successfully.

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/bin/Rscript.exe" ,"D:/RTest/MyScript.R");
    pb.start();
```